# Drop and include columns in a DataFrame in all possible combinations(To train a ML model) except one column(target column)

Tags: python, pandas

I expect something like this,

df (original):

```
   index  feature1(target column)  feature2  feature3  feature4
0      0                        1         2         3         4
1      1                        1         2         3         4
2      2                        1         2         3         4
3      3                        1         2         3         4
```

df1:

```
   feature1(target column)  feature2  feature3
0                        1         2         3
1                        1         2         3
2                        1         2         3
3                        1         2         3
```

df2:

```
   feature1(target column)  feature2  feature4
0                        1         2         4
1                        1         2         4
2                        1         2         4
3                        1         2         4
```

df3:

```
   feature1(target column)  feature3  feature4
0                        1         3         4
1                        1         3         4
2                        1         3         4
3                        1         3         4
```

df4:

```
   feature1(target column)  feature2  feature4
0                        1         2         4
1                        1         2         4
2                        1         2         4
3                        1         2         4
```

Comment: Do not invent the wheel, there are many options to train ML models. I suggest you to use grid-search and cross validation. Regards.

Comment: Not just is good practice is being kind to other people-coworkers reading your code.

Comment: where are your efforts?

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to programming as a whole. I can see something is wrong about the way i asked this question. Hope this community understands that this is due  to my lack of experience in asking questions and programming.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered so far, you are trying to perform feature engineering. Feature engineering, in short, is the process of selecting the best features for model training. There are multiple techniques out there like: forward feature selection, backward feature elimination, PCA, LDA, etc. These are divided into 2 main categories:

1. Feature Selection
2. Feature Extraction

I suggest you read about them. There are plenty of implementations of these methods you can find on GitHub, StackOverflow, or in ML libraries

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to programming as a whole. I can see something is wrong about the way i asked this question. Hope you understand that this is due  to my lack of experience in asking questions and programming. Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Sorry, I totally messed up this question. I also want to reduce the number of columns. This code works fine but the number of columns stays constant . Can you please modify this. Thanks in advance. I couldn't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputations to do so.

Comment: reduce the number of columns? Could you give an example

Comment: target column and feature2 column only (total two columns) ,                                                         target and feature2 and feature3(total 3 columns) . something that should also increase and decrease the number of columns.  This is to which combination of features have the most impact on the target column, to give you an idea i have more than 50+ features.

Comment: Do you want remove a specific column in every iteration?

Comment: not specific column a randomly chosen one

Comment: I have changed the answer, please have a look

Comment: Also, try to add such details in the question so that others can better understand and give answers

Comment: Thank you so much..for your time and  efforts.

Comment: @Juan No problem. Also, if you find the answers helpful, please try to mark them ok so that others can benefit